# Is this function uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

My question is simple.

> Let $f(x)=x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x}), x\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Is this function uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?

I think it is not uniformly continuous when $x$ goes to $\infty$

Comment: What is your reason for thinking that? You may be able to make a proof from your reason.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know this function is close to $x^2$ for large $x$ ,
and $x^2$ is not uniformly conti. on there and I proved this using the definition of the uniformly continuous.
But I can't find such large $x$ for $x^3sin(1/x)$.

Comment: "Close to $x^2$" is very good. What's left is to quantify that closeness in order to get a proof. How close is $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ to $\frac{1}{x}$ (for large $x$)?

Comment: hint: $\sin(1/x) = 1/x - 1/(6x^3) + o(1/x^3)$ for $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Using @user251257 hint: Let $\delta >0$ s.t. $|x-y| < \delta$. Now,
\begin{align*} 
|f(x)-f(y)|&= |x^3\sin(1/x)-y^3\sin(1/y)\\
&=|x^3(1/x - 1/(6x^3))-y^3(1/y - 1/(6y^3))|\\
&=|x^2-y^2|\\
&\leq \delta(|x|+|y|)  \; \text{(from triangle inequality and using $|x-y| < \delta$)}
\end{align*}
Clearly $f \rightarrow \infty $ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Edit: As per suggestion, let $y=x+\frac{\delta}{2}$, then third equality becomes
$|x^2-(x+\delta/2)^2|=|-\delta^2/4-2\delta x| \leq \delta^2/4 + 2\delta |x| \rightarrow \infty$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: seems good to me

Comment: it is better explicitly to take $y = x+\delta / 2$ and to show that $f(x)-f(x+\delta/2)$ is unbound for $x\to\infty$

Comment: @chandresh
I have a question.

'$|f(x)-f(y)|\le g(x),$  where $ g \rightarrow \infty $  as  $ x \rightarrow \infty$'

 implies 

$|f(x)-f(y)| \rightarrow \infty$  as $x \rightarrow \infty$??

Comment: @mireiffe: nope. Better $(x+\delta/2)^2 - x^2 \ge x\delta \to \infty$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @user251257 Okay now I got it. But I have another question... You said $\sin(1/x) = 1/x - 1/(6x^3) + o(1/x^3)$ for $x\to\infty$. Is this a Taylor's theorem thing? but then the last term should be $o(1/x^5)$, isn't it?

Comment: @mireiffe: It is Taylor's theorem. I wrote down the weakest form that was needed.

Comment: @user251257: Thank you very much. Finally I got all